# Python and arrays

Tags: python

I know that python is a crazy language because of it's cycles constructions :)

So, I have an array of numbers but in string type:

```
a = ['1', '40', '356', '...']
```

I need this or a copy of this array but with `float` type instead of string. The only thing is that the code should be in one line.

Help me, please :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`map()`*<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) and [`float()`*<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#float):

```
b = map(float, a)
```

Comment: this is one of the few cases where map/reduce are cleaner than comprehensions

Comment: @Gabi: Exactly, using `map` with built-in functions usually beats (list) comprehension.

Comment: Great answer :) I love python. Thanks

Comment: but `map` returns a iterator on python3... So you'll have to change the code when migrating. A list comprehension will always work

Comment: 2to3 will take care of that. Porting without it is crazy talk (except perhaps some very rare circumstances) anyway.

Comment: @delnan of course 2to3 will fix it. It will fix all `map(func, it)` to `list(map(func, it))` which is pretty bad

Answer (score 8):

```
 a = ['1', '40', '356', '...']
 b = [float(x) for x in a]
```

This is called a list comprehension.  It's a very powerful feature of Python, and you can read more about list comprehensions here:

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions