# How to change a list of strings to integers - Python

Tags: python, string, integer

I need to change a list of strings into a list of integers how do i do this

i.e

('1', '1', '1', '1', '2') into (1,1,1,1,2).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert strings into integers in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642154/how-to-convert-strings-into-integers-in-python). [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396733/python-and-arrays) is also similar. Not to mention [these ones](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+convert+list+of+strings+to+integers). Please use the search before you ask a new question.

Comment: nitpick: those are tuples, not lists.

Comment: @Wooble: covered in my answer now. i wanted to write it from the beginning, but you have to be fast when answering such easy questions ;)

Answer (score 8):

Use [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
strtuple = ('1', '1', '1', '1', '2')
intlist = [int(s) for s in strtuple]
```

## Stuff for completeness:

As your “list” is in truth a [tuple](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq), i.e. a immutable list, you would have to use a generator expression together with a tuple constructor to get another tuple back:

```
inttuple = tuple(int(s) for s in strtuple)
```

The “generator expression” i talk about looks like this when not wrapped in a constructor call, and returns a generator this way.

```
intgenerator = (int(s) for s in strtuple)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `map` function.

```
vals = ('1', '1', '1', '1', '2')
result = tuple(map(int, vals))
print result
```

Output:

```
(1, 1, 1, 1, 2)
```

A performance comparison with the list comprehension:

```
from timeit import timeit
print timeit("map(int, vals)", "vals = '1', '2', '3', '4'")
print timeit("[int(s) for s in strlist]", "strlist = ('1', '1', '1', '1', '2')")
```

Output:

```
3.08675879197
4.08549801721
```

And with longer lists:

```
print timeit("map(int, vals)", "vals = tuple(map(str, range(10000)))", number = 1000)
print timeit("[int(s) for s in strlist]", "strlist = tuple(map(str, range(10000)))", number = 1000)
```

Output:

```
6.2849350965
7.36635214811
```

It appears that, (on my machine) in this case, the `map` approach is faster than the list comprehension.

Comment: Definitely nice to see map mentioned and point out that there is more than one approach. With that said, list comprehension tends to be easier to read, more pythonic, and (generally, there are edge case exceptions) faster.

Comment: @TimothyAWiseman: Using built-in functions with `map` should be faster than list comprehension. So this is a perfect edge case ;)

Comment: @TimothyAWiseman: `map` is faster in this case.  See my update.

Comment: i think that newbies should learn the more pythonic and mightier approach first.

Comment: oh, and no offense: your time measuring sucks. you have to try it with different list sizes to get meaningful results; plus, for lists this tiny, the results have exactly no meaning.

Comment: No offense taken.  The question was asked with a tiny list, so I figured it was a good representation.  I'll include a longer list in an attempt to suck less.  I disagree that they have no meaning though.  That's the aggregate time over a million iterations, so it must be repeatable.

Comment: what i want to say: in case of such tiny datasets, speed is 1. no factor, and 2. misleading, as the overhead of whoknowswhat most likely has much more impact. also, i get different results with, and without braces and with longer and shorter variable names (“vals” is faster than “strlist”). you are right: map with builtins *is* faster, but who cares when it’s one of the four milliseconds.

Comment: @flying sheep:  I wouldn't have mentioned the speed issue, other than to reply to the statement that comprehensions are usually faster.  That may be true, but I wanted to point out that it wasn't in this case.

Comment: @recursive let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2590/discussion-between-flying-sheep-and-recursive)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that it is faster in this case, you ahve an excellent point.  I think I would still prefer the list comprehension for the readability, but always good to have hard data to work with when making the decision.

Answer (score 2):

```
map(int, ls)
```

Where `ls` is your list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehension which would look roughly like:

```
newList = [int(x) for x in oldList]
```